# Use $n$ as regressor in logistic regression with binomial proportion target

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model

In a logistic regression with binomial proportion target variable -- i.e. $Z_i \sim \text{Bin}(n_i,p_i)$ with target $Y_i := Z_i/n_i$ -- is there any reason for not allowing $n_i$ to be one of the regressors?

Comment: Maybe you can tell us **why** you want to include it? There is nothing in the maths prohibiting it, but I guess there must be quite special occasions for it to be useful ...

Comment: Yes, that is also what I figured. I would include it because there seems to be a negative relationship between p and n in my data: the larger n gets, the smaller the proportion of successes tends to be.

Comment: While it is mathematically possible to include n in the model, it is very very rare to do so. What you say is a very strong signal that something may be wrong with your model and that the data are not really binomial distributed. If it was me, I would be rechecking and revisiting my assumptions. For example, is it possible that you have entered the proportions $Y_i$ into a software function that was expecting to get the counts $Z_i$?. That would induce the negative correlation that you report.

Comment: Or is n simply correlated with an important covariate because of a common cause? E.g., what proportion of the population are farmers? Larger towns will have larger n and smaller p.

Comment: @GordonSmyth. Thanks, those are good suggestions. As for the software, I think no, because I am just using the glm function in R in what I am fairly certain is the proper way. I would prefer not to give details about the data set/application because it is related to my work. I thought about the following example as an analogy: Assign 100 people random numbers n_i and build a model for the number push ups out of n_i that they can complete. Then I might include some personal characteristics (age, weight,..) in my model, but probably n_i too. Does this make sense or am I missing something?

Comment: OK, that's helpful. The pushup example is a perfect example of data for which the binomial assumptions do not hold. The binomial distribution assumes that trials are independent, but pushups become gradually harder to complete as you do more. If a person can't perform the 50th pushup, then they certainly can't complete the 51st either. The pushups are not independent and hence the number completed out of n_i is not binomial. (I guess it would be underdispersed relative to binomial).

Comment: Ah yes, good point. Thanks for helping me think it through. I upvoted your comments.